# Admob configure mediation with iAd

Tags: admob, iad

In Admob I have 2 ways to configure iAd mediation with Admob

1. eCPM - (I set eCPM per ad network)
2. % - I set % shares
   (+ country targeting as optional choice)

I wish to show iAd when  available and admob in rest cases.

What should I enter? (admob docs are not helpful)

Also some article with examples how it will work when I enter certain values in eCPM field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a relevant blog post [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/06/distributing-ad-requests-for-admob.html) on how eCPM and percentages work.

For eCPM, AdMob will order the networks based on their eCPM values in descending order. So if you have iAd at $1.00 and AdMob at $0.25, iAd will be the first network, and AdMob will backfill the rest of the requests. If you have Ad Network 3 at $0.10, the order will be iAd, AdMob, then Network 3 filling any requests iAd and AdMob failed to fill.